# React MUI components become squashed when navigating to and from another page

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using mui components in my React app, including Select, as below.
When the page loads for the first time, they appear as expected, like this:

[image]

When I navigate to another page (I'm using Routes `react-router-dom`) and then back to the page with the mui components, they become squashed like this:

[image]

No other page is using mui components and I have not added any custom styles other than the inline styles in my code. This happens even if I navigate to and from an empty page with no styling.

What could be happening here?

```js
import { Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';

...

<Select
    value={team}
    onChange={handleTeamChange}
    displayEmpty
    style={{ flexBasis: '45%' }}
>
    <MenuItem value=""><em>Select Team</em></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="A">A</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="B">B</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Comment: did you add theme provider to root file?

Comment: Thanks @amirrezamojarad, I hadn't added a theme provider (didn't realise I had to). If I manually customise the components this way, they stay the same style when navigating.

Comment: check this link
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30436#issuecomment-1003339715